# Идентификатор пользователя в URL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица USERS в MYSQL, где у каждого пользователя свой ID. Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь входил в свой кабинет, в URL был строка `http://suite/$id`, где $ID = id пользователя. Не могу придумать, как реализовать...

Comment: .htaccess вам в помощь:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо почитать о [ЧПУ (Friendly URL)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_%28%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%29) и [mod_rewrite](http://www.seoblog.com.ua/2008/11/04/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-and-mod_rewrite/) в общем, чтобы понять суть, а так же посмотреть [примеры реализации](https://www.google.com.ua/#hl=ru&sa=X&ei=QFEKUJlMpfbhBP3G8MUK&ved=0CFcQvwUoAQ&q=mod_rewrite+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B+%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f04473a6ac7cb78a&biw=1586&bih=1016).

Если очень образно и схематически, то ссылки у вас могут иметь вид: http://mysite.ru/user_profile/user_id/100500 и в этом виде отображаться в адресной строке пользователя. С помощью заранее прописанных правил, эти ссылки преобразуются в более привычный вид: http://mysite.ru/user_profile.php?user_id=100500 и обрабатываете запросы, как при обычном формировании ссылок

Answer (score 1):

В таком духе :

```
login.php
        <?
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $res = $db->query("select * from users where login=$login and pass=$pass");
        $res = $db->fetchAssoc($res);
        if (intval($res['id'])>0) 
      ``{define('USER_LOGGED',TRUE);header('Location:http://example.com/user/'.$res['id'].'');}
        else echo "Error";
        ?>
```